# How to search for specific format in a string?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate connection string that user will paste in a textbox in which i want to validate that if user has specified database name or not.

Eg of valid connection string for sql server :

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;

Or

Server=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;
```

Suppose user paste connection string like below :

```
Server=myServerAddress;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Here in above connection string user has not specified database name hence i would like to give alert to user that please specify database name.

So for sql server below 2 formats are correct for specifying database :

```
Database=myDataBase
Or
Initial Catalog=myDataBase
```

So i want to validate below format which should be there compulsory in connection string:

```
Database or Initial Catalog = <DatabaseName>
```

But here in my code how do i specify that either database or initial catalog keyword should be there and with above format in regex expression?

```js
var conn = "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;";

    function containsWord(string, word) {
        return new RegExp('(?:[^.\w]|^|^\\W+)' + word + '(?:[^.\w]|\\W(?=\\W+|$)|$)').test(string);
    }
    
    console.log(containsWord(conn,'Database'));
```

[Connection string source](https://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Comment: Just use OR operator: `containsWord(conn,'Database') || containsWord(conn,'Initial Catalog')`

Comment: @hindmost:But then i have to call my function twice to validate that and how do i validate format in regex?

Comment: What's the problem with calling a function twice?

Comment: @hindmost:Actually i was thinking like there should be a way to check that 2 keyword in single regex expression

Comment: _how do i validate format in regex?_ Your code already does this. You don't know what your code actually does?

Comment: you decided to use regexes - now you have two problems...

Comment: _..there should be a way to check that 2 keyword in single regex._ If I understood correct, you have to check 4 (5) keywords, not just 2. So such single regex become a bit complex. It would be better to write an utility function searching single `key=value` occurrence and call it for each needed keyword. Your code implements such approach, though it seems that the function needs to be improved.

Comment: several of the comments and answers appear not to have spotted that the `Database` and `Initial Catalog` options are _mutually exclusive_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regexes really aren't the best solution for this.  It's better to parse the connection string (making the assumption that semicolons can't appear within the variables).

This (ES6) function returns a `Map` of key value pairs:

```
function parseConnectionString(cstr) {
    return cstr.trim()                // remove whitespace from either end
            .split(/\s*;\s*/)         // split on semicolons (& removing whitespace)
            .filter(x => x.length)    // removes trailing empty entry 
            .map(kv => kv.split('=')) // create [key, value] pairs
            .reduce((m, [k, v]) => m.set(k, v), new Map());
                                      // and convert those to a Map
}
```

and this one then separately validates that either of the two keys (but not both) are present in the parsed map:

```
function isValidConnection(c) {
    var db = c.get('Database');
    var ic = c.get('Initial Catalog');

    if (db !== undefined && ic !== undefined) return false; // mutually exclusive
    return Boolean((db && db.length > 0) || (ic && ic.length > 0));
}
```

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me and this is working fine but the only problem is if i dont specify database name then also it is returning true.

Comment: @Learning it works for me - I can't reproduce that.  Or did you mean if you do `Database=;` with no value it fails?

Comment: @Learning I've updated the `isValidConnection` function to ensure that it explicitly rejects empty values

Comment: If i use  connectionstring like this :Server=myServerAddress;Database;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword; or this : Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword; then your code is returning undefined

Comment: Yeah i was talking about your second comment only.it fails when i use Database= or only Database.Note  i dont specify database name so it is invalid

Comment: @Learning the updated code should take account of that now.  It should reject any string that has both `Database` and `Initial Catalog` as keys (with or without values) and then also if either of those are supplied but empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143969/discussion-between-learning-and-alnitak).

Answer (score 2):

If it's ok to use ES6, using [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) can change the signature so that multiple words can be given, without changing the existing calls with a single parameter

```js
function containsWord(string, ...words) {
  return  new RegExp('(?:[^.\w]|^|^\\W+)' + words.join('|') + '(?:[^.\w]|\\W(?=\\W+|$)|$)').test(string); //left the regex unaltered, only joined the words with or '|'
}

var conn = "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;";
console.log(containsWord(conn,'Initial Catalog', 'Database')); //true
console.log(containsWord(conn,'Initial Catalog')); //false
console.log(containsWord(conn,'Database')); //true
```

Note, I left the regular expression as is (other than joining the words, so that the regex is only called once), assuming there are more reasons for its setup, but you might want to use an ignore case parameter for the regex. Of course there are many alternatives such as splitting on `;` first, but the main clue for making life easy are the rest parameters

PS, strictly speaking you could have used your current function as well by calling it with the parameter `'Intial Catalog|Database'`

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me..Why your second console.log is return false because if i will just supply Initial Catalog then it is correct

Comment: The second returns false for this specific example because the given connection string does not contain `'Initial Catalog'`. The call  is only included to illustrate the difference between the first call, where both options are given as parameters, and the calls with single words. The actual check should only use the first option.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const s1 = 'Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;';
const s2 = 'Server=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;';

const sBad = 'Server=myServerAddress;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;';

const reqWords = ['Server', 'Database', 'User Id', 'Password'];
const reqWords2 = ['Server', 'Initial Catalog', 'User Id', 'Password'];

const checkFields = (s, rw) => {
  const words = s.split(';').map(a => a.split('=')[0]).filter(q => q.length);
  return (rw.length === words.length && rw.every(w => words.includes(w))) ? true : false;
}

const checkAgainst = (s) => (r1, r2) => checkFields(s, r1) || checkFields(s, r2);

const check = (s) => checkAgainst(s)(reqWords, reqWords2)

const r1 = check(s1);
const r2 = check(s2);
const r3 = check(sBad);

console.log(r1, r2, r3);
```

If used in browser, consider swapping `const` to `var` if there are any compatibility issues.

The code splits your string into chunks and checks if all required fields are present.

`checkFields` checks a string against predefined values, `checkAgainst` combines result for 2 alternative cases.

Answer (score 1):

please check code snippet

```js
function CheckWordExists(word) {
var ConnectionString = "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"

var SplitWords = ConnectionString.split(";");
var IsWordExits = false;
for (var i = 0; i < SplitWords.length; i++) {
    if(SplitWords[i].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(word.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
        var databaseName = SplitWords[i].split('=')[1];
        alert(databaseName);
        //you can check database name here for validation.
        IsWordExists = true;
    }
}


    return IsWordExists;
}

alert(CheckWordExists('Database'))
```

Comment: I dont want to use jquery library for this.I would like to use javascript only

Comment: There are 2 keywords which i would like to check and that is Initial Catelog and Database so do i need to call your function twice to validate that?.

Comment: using pure javascript. and you can modify function as per your need.

Comment: either you can call function twice or you can pass comma separated values in function argument and then check values by spliting in function